# How stop CellValueChanged firing while populating?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I have a form that contains several DataGridView's. They are being cleared and populated programmatically while the program is running. This is based on cells being altered in one of the DataGridViews by the user in the form. The user changing a cell triggers clearing and repopulating all the DataGridViews including the one they interact with.

So now to my question. Can I avoid CellValueChanged being triggered everytime the DataGridViews are cleared and repopulated programmatically? Instead it should only be triggered when the user edits a cell in the form.

I've tried searching for an answer with no success, so I hope this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Event handlers can be added and _removed_ programmatically.

Comment: So what you're suggesting @Steve would be to remove the event handler while I clear and repopulate the DataGridView and add it again afterwards so it only catches user events?

Comment: Yes, the answer below shows how to do it. Remember to use a try/finally around your loading code to reinstall the handler also in case of exceptions (unless the exception is so severe that you choose to terminate the program)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I doubt that you can stop CellValueChanged event from being triggered, other than by removing your handlers(events will be still triggered, but there won't be any handlers for it):

```
private dgv_ThatCausesChanges_CellValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    this.otherDGV.CellValueChanged -= this.dgv_OtherDGVCellValueChanged;

    try // To make sure that handlers are reinstatiated even on exception thanks @Steve
    {       

         // Change other DGVs
    }
    finally
    {    
         this.otherDGV.CellValueChanged += this.dgv_OtherDGVCellValueChanged;
    }
}
```

Or as alternative solution just add some flag, that will be checked in every handler:

```
private bool IsChanging;

private dgv_ThatCausesChanges_CellValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.IsChanging = true;

    try // To make sure that handlers are reinstatiated even on exception thanks @Steve
    {  

        // Change other DGVs
    }
    finally
    {    
        this.IsCHanging = false;
    }
}

private dgv_OtherDGVCellValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsChanging)
        return;

    // Handle changes
}
```

Comment: I think that adding and removing the event handler is better than introducing a global variable. In any case a try/finally is mandatory in this situations

Comment: @Steve Adding and removing handlers reduces dependencies for other DGV, but makes source DGV responsible for remembering which DGV should be changed, while Form level variable simplifies life for source DGV, but makes dependent DGV responsible for correct handling of the status. So, it is just the matter of tradeoffs and preferences. Try catch blocks for handler removal is a necessary overall practice, but whether they are needed for static UI is another question - they will probably just hide bugs in this situation.

Comment: As you say it is a matter of preference. Mine is to avoid at all costs global variables also in this elementary case. For the try/finally I was just remembering that (if the exception is not a dead stop) the event handler or the global variable should be reverted to the correct value in the finally block

Comment: @Steve I have added finally blocks. And form level variable is no more global than form events.

Comment: you give me a solution to end the nightmate, thank you

Answer (score 2):

With thanks to @Eugene and @Steve I have come to a solution. I have model classes that call update methods in my GUI class. When these update methods are called, I remove the event handler so that clearing and refreshing the DataGridView doesn't result in several calls to `CellValueChanged` as seen below:

```
public void updateSomeDataGridView(String[][] someData)
{
    this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged -= this.DataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

    //Repopulate DataGridView with new data.

    dataGridView1.Refresh();
    this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += this.DataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if CellValueChanged didn't fire for each character typed in a cell. Too bad they don't have a RowValueChanged event. That would be far more useful